# how to order elements on an event using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a situation, where I want to position certain elements based on an event. For example:

```
<div id="leftBox">
    <div class="green">GREEN</div>
    <div class="blue">BLUE</div>
    <div class="red">RED</div>
</div>



<div id="rightBox">
    <div class="green">GREEN</div>
    <div class="blue">BLUE</div>
    <div class="red">RED</div>
    <div class="green">GREEN</div>
    <div class="blue">BLUE</div>
    <div class="red">RED</div>
    <div class="green">GREEN</div>
    <div class="blue">BLUE</div>
    <div class="red">RED</div>
</div>
```

when I mouse over on **#leftBox .green**, I want all elements in **#rightBox with .green** on top, like:

```
<div id="rightBox">
    <div class="green">GREEN</div>
    <div class="green">GREEN</div>
    <div class="green">GREEN</div>
    <div class="blue">BLUE</div>
    <div class="red">RED</div>
    <div class="blue">BLUE</div>
    <div class="red">RED</div>
    <div class="blue">BLUE</div>
    <div class="red">RED</div>
</div>
```

and like the same for **.blue** and **.red**

Comment: i tried something. please check it, friend.

Comment: friend, if this solution works for you, you should take it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("div#leftBox div").mouseover(function(){

        $("div#rightBox ."+$(this).attr('class')).each(function() {

             $("div#rightBox").prepend($(this));
        });

    });

});
```

This also works fine, you can check the demo here, http://jsfiddle.net/S8TXq/

If you want to retain the other elements order, just try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("div#leftBox div").mouseover(function(){
        main = $('#rightBox div').clone(true);
        $("div#rightBox ."+$(this).attr('class')).each(function() {

             $("div#rightBox").prepend($(this));
        });

    }).mouseout(function() {
    $('#rightBox').empty().append(main);});

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S8TXq/5/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var main, address;
    $('#leftBox div').mouseenter(function() {
        address = $(this).attr('class');
        var stack = [],
        tmp = [],
        total = [];
        main = $('#rightBox div').clone(true);
        stack = $('#rightBox div.'+ address +'').remove();
        tmp = $('#rightBox div');
        total = $.merge(stack, tmp);
        $.each(total,
        function() {
            $(this).appendTo('#rightBox').show();
        })
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $('#rightBox').empty().append(main);});
```